# Can you see in different planes using Beast Sense?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes

A ranger cast *beast sense* on a war hound mount/beast companion and sent the poor guy through a hell gate. I immediately told him that he no longer perceived the world from the hound's perspective because it was now on a different plane. However, he pointed out that the spell said nothing about any range limits, which is true. I ruled that since not even a warlock's special familiar (pact of the chain) using the incantation *voice of the chain master* could bypass planar boundaries, his 2nd level ranger spell also couldn't.

What are the limitations of beast sense and similar divination spells regarding planar boundaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, spells do not fail when the target moves to another plane. Spells which are limited in this way specify the limitation in the spell description. For example, *Telepathic Bond* includes this clause:

> The
>   communication
>   is
>   possible
>   over
>   any
>   distance,
>   though
>   it
>   can’t
>   extend
>   to
>   other
>   planes
>   of
>   existence.

*Beast Sense* does not include a similar clause, so it would not normally fail when the target changed planes.

However, as always, you're the DM, so if you decide that spells like these can't work between planes, then that's the rule for your game.

Comment: Thanks i see your point, and i think you are right, im just a little concerned about the implications this will have in my campaign, I hate to rule anything out just because it complicates my life as dm, I dont want to limit any potential from my player's builds as long as they respect the game's mechanics, so it turns out a rangers 2nd level spell beats many wizard/warlock spells in this particular aspect, way to go ranger.

Comment: @PieroManavella If it helps, remember that, unlike a warlock's familiar, the ranger can't control their animal companion's every move. In fact, unless the ranger is also using a spell that lets him communicate with the animal companion, they can't even give it commands.

Comment: @PieroManavella One thing to note is that a normal animal on a foreign plane may have anxiety something fierce, depending on the plane. I would say that in the Feywild they would be fine to an extent and just sleep more but someplace like Hell or the Abyss the communication could get problematic as the animal may have difficultly processing the "wrongness" of the plane.